# What does TCP packet [P.] flag means in tcpdump's output?

Tags: tcp, tcpdump

If an IP x.x.x.x connects to IP z.z.z.z using [P.] Flag for TCP packet what exactly this [P.] flag means? Does it means that x.x.x.x sends some data to z.z.z.z?

Answer (score 6):

#### What exactly this [P.] Flag

It is a PUSH flag.

> Tcpflags are some combination of S (SYN), F (FIN), P (PUSH), R (RST), U (URG), W (ECN CWR), E (ECN-Echo) or `.' (ACK), or `none' if no flags are set.

Source [Manpage of TCPDUMP](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html)

> The purpose of push function and the PUSH flag is to push data through
>   from the sending user to the receiving user. It does not provide a
>   record service.
>
> There is a coupling between the push function and the use of buffers
>   of data that cross the TCP/user interface. Each time a PUSH flag is
>   associated with data placed into the receiving user's buffer, the
>   buffer is returned to the user for processing even if the buffer is
>   not filled. If data arrives that fills the user's buffer before a PUSH
>   is seen, the data is passed to the user in buffer size units.

Source [[PSH,ACK] wireshark capture - Wireshark Q&A](https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/20423/pshack-wireshark-capture)

> **PSH and the PUSH function**
>
> When you send data, your `TCP` buffers it. So if you send a character
>   it won't send it immediately but wait to see if you've got more. But
>   maybe you want it to go straight on the wire: this is where the PUSH
>   function comes in. If you PUSH data your TCP will immediately create a
>   segment (or a few segments) and *push* them.
>
> But the story doesn't stop here. When the peer TCP receives the data,
>   it will naturally buffer them **it won't disturb the application for
>   each and every byte**. Here's where the `PSH` flag  kicks in. If a
>   receiving TCP sees the PSH flag it will immediately *push* the data to
>   the application.
>
> There's no API to set the `PSH` flag. Typically it is set by the
>   kernel when it empties the buffer. From TCP/IP Illustrated:
>
> > This flag is conventionally used to indicate that the buffer at the side sending the packet has been 
> >     emptied in conjunction with sending the packet. In other words, when the packet with the PSH bit field set left the sender, the sender had
> >     no more data to send.
>
> But be aware Stevens also says:
>
> > Push (the receiver should pass this data to the application as soon as
> >     possible—**not reliably implemented or used**)

Source [Difference between push and urgent flags in TCP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9153777/3536342), answer by [cnicutar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714501/cnicutar)

Comment: However in practice all TCP implementations ignore the PUSH flag completely and behave as though it is always set. It is an anachronism that can be ignored.